# Chatter Feed Posts / Updates Disappears

Tags: chatter, chatter-feed

Issue: An opportunity previously had Items displayed in the chatter feed above the record. Documentation was printed out to prove that the feed existed and had data. However, looking at the record today, there is **NO DATA** at all in the chatter feed of the given record

What I have looked for:

- Audit trail to see if Chatter was turned off then back on - Negative (Even though it should not have removed posts)
- Web search for this issue, nothing found, or it was buried too deep, or google foo is light today

Does anyone have any idea why chatter feed items for an opportunity would be removed? It has been 10 months since they printed the document and the LastModified date was the same as on the document....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google foo was better today...

It seems the only items in their chatter feed were field updates / changes and I found this tidbit in the Chatter specifications:

> The number of system-generated tracked feed updates. Currently tracked
>   feed updates that are older than 45 days and have no likes or comments
>   are deleted automatically. The tracked feed updates no longer appear
>   in the feed. However, if auditing is enabled for a tracked field, the
>   audit history for that field is still available

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_collaboration.htm&language=en_US